# Windows Explorer filename sort order: why ×a before 'a?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, sorting, filenames

Have a look at this filename sort order in Windows 10 Explorer:

[image]

The character `'` is mostly sorted before `×`. But why is it the other way around for `'a` vs. `×a`?

Comment: It is probably ignored entirely so quoted text is sorted in a useful way.

Comment: The 2nd one has a space in it.

Comment: Here are the rules https://unicode.org/reports/tr10/

Comment: @user1292580 The document is long. Which part of it describes the treatment of the `'` character? What source says that these rules are used by Windows Explorer?

Comment: Sorting used to be simple. ANSI Characters were sorted by their code point so <space> (code 32) comes before <A> (code 65). Their were 256 code points. With Unicode it sorts culturally appropriately for every language in the world. Multiple code points are the same (eg <e> with <combining \`> is the same as <è> and will be sorted the same. Explorer adds an extra layer of complexity with logical sorting. This is where embedded numbers are sorted by number not code point or Unicode sort order (there are tables).

Answer (score 2):

Natural sorting in Windows Explorer simply ignores (leading) quotes. Only what comes after counts.

[image: sort order]

1. " G"
2. " Hello"
3. "' Hello"
4. " I"
5. "×Hello"
6. "G"
7. "Hello"
8. "'Hello"
9. "I"

So in your example, "'a" is equivalent to "a" which comes after special characters. If anything, it’s more surprising that leading spaces change the sort order.

Comment: Oddly enough, more *pseudo-random* first characters ends up to the following sort order (space-separated list):  `‼a ¦a €a ।a +a ±a ×a ▬a ¶a ⛔a 1 ⁷a ₿a a 'a -a −a —a b ℉a` where the first characters are *Double Exclamation Mark*, *Broken Bar*, *Euro Sign*, *Devanagari Danda*, *Plus Sign*, *Plus-Minus Sign*, *Multiplication Sign*, *Black Rectangle*, *Pilcrow Sign*, *No Entry*, *Digit One*, *Superscript Seven*, *BITCOIN SIGN*, *Latin Small Letter A*, *Apostrophe*, *Hyphen-Minus*, *Minus Sign*, *Em Dash*, *Latin Small Letter B*, *Degree Fahrenheit*, respectively…

Comment: Just realized that this answer doesn't exlpain the order `‼a ¦a €a ।a +a ±a ×a ▬a ¶a ⛔a 1 ⁷a ₿a a 'a -a −a —a b ℉a`, so I have to unaccept this answer for now.

Comment: Fine by me, but please consider what you asked. Don’t arbitrarily extend the question later.